# Collapse repeating characters

Tags: bash, string, replace

Is there a more Bashist way than `echo "$PWD//" | sed -e 's#//\+#/#g'` to replace repeating slashes with a single one?

Thanks [Steven D](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/collapse-repeating-characters/11390#11390), now there's a fully working function to find the *longest common path of two or more paths*: [path_common](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bash_aliases#L117).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a "Bash-only" answer, but perhaps useful:

```
echo "$PWD///" | tr -s '/'
```

Comment: The "squeeze" (-s) option to tr can be used on a range of characters, too: echo "aabbcc" | tr -s '[ac]' should yeild "abbc"

Answer (score 5):

Possible in "pure bash", but only with `extglob` active.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ A="////qsd/////sdfgfg//qsd//////"
$ echo ${A//\/+(\/)/\/}
/qsd/sdfgfg/qsd/
```

Comment: @Mat.. The replacement needs to be `/` (not `\/`) on my system... ????

Comment: @fred.bear: both work here (bash 4.1.9(2))

Comment: @Mat.. version 4.1.5(1) ... That must be it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Bash only, by using a variable:

```
# code:
shopt -s extglob
A="$PWD//"; 
echo "Original: $A"; 
echo "Result:   ${A//+(\/)//}"

# output:
Original: /home/myhome/Projects/Bob/build//
Result:   /home/myhome/Projects/Bob/build/
```

- // = search and replace, keep searching and replacing
- +(/) = match one or more of "/"
- // = replace with, "/"

For a better visual example let's say that "z"s need to be squeezed to better see this without needing to escape the slash and not to have our search/replace confused with the infrastructure of ${VAR//pattern/string}:

```
# code:
shopt -s extglob
A=zzz/zzz/zzzzz/zzzz/zzzz; 
echo $A; 
echo ${A//+(z)/z}

# output:
zzz/zzz/zzzzz/zzzz/zzzz
z/z/z/z/z
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: **Mat**(+1) has got the right idea... my answer only works for odd numbers of "/"

it does *not* need "extglob" to be set.

var="$PWD///"; var="${var//\/\//}" ; echo "$var"